# MS Teams custom tab SSO not working on desktop App

Tags: iframe, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, saml-2.0

We have set up our application as a custom Microsoft Teams app. The application is working just fine in the browser but fails to load in the Desktop APP. The application uses Azure Active Directory to perform the login through the saml2.0 implementation and is embedded through an iFrame.

Can't find a good way to debug what the issue might be. The AAD logs are always empty and the DevTools do not show what's happening in the embedded iFrame.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or might know of a way to try and debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite common, that it works fine in browser but not in desktop, and there are probably several reasons for that, not least of which that the popup experience is easier to control in browser versus the actual Teams desktop sandbox. It's also common, I think, that people try to launch their own popup to handle the login, which you can't actually do in the Teams desktop. It's a bit wierd, but basically Teams desktop launches a popup for you, which loads your login page, which in turn then needs to do a -redirect- because you're now in a new browser page.

In any case, in my experience, it's always because I've done something wrong, that's why desktop doesn't work correctly. My suggestion is to follow the docs -exactly- and it should work fine.

The most important doc is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?WT.mc_id=m365-43962-cxa#develop-an-sso-microsoft-teams-tab), which really does give some quite straightforward step-by-step. You can also check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kruUnaZgQaY) which helps as well.